# How to get an json object in JsonArray using Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a json object in an array using the following code. The code seems to be finding the json object in the array, however, it fails to update the json object inside the json array. It doesn't give any error so that's what makes it more confusing.

```
function addOrUpdateAppointment(jsonObject, isDatabaseOperationSuccessful) {
    var docID = jsonObject.doctorID; // this is _id from db sent to the doctor upon logging in
    console.log("jsonPssed: ", {_id : docID});
    DoctorModel.findOne({_id : docID, 'appointmentList.patientID': jsonObject.appointment.patientID}, {'appointmentList.$.patientID': jsonObject.appointment.patientID},function(err, foundData) {
        console.log("found data", foundData);
        if(err) {
            console.error("error in find doctor for adding the appointment", err);
            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(false, foundData);
            return;
        }
        else {
            // since no document matched your query, add the appointment
            if (!foundData) {
                DoctorModel.update(
                    {_id: docID},
                    {$push: {appointmentList: jsonObject.appointment}},
                    function(err, pushedData) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.error("error in adding", err);
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(false, pushedData);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("adding successful", pushedData, "inserted: ", jsonObject.appointment);
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(true, pushedData);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            // since that appointment already exists, update it
            else {
                foundData.update({'_id':docID,'doctors.appointmentList.patientID' : jsonObject.appointment.patientID}, {$set: {'doctors.appointmentList.$.dateAndTime': jsonObject.appointment.dateAndTime}},
                    function(err, updatedData) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("error in updating", err);
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(false, foundData);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (!updatedData) {
                                console.log("updating failed", updatedData);
                                isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(true, foundData);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("updating successful", updatedData);
                                isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(true, foundData);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Schema:

```
doctorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name : String,
        appointmentList : Array // array of jsonObjects of dates and time
    });
```

Data that I am passing to addOrUpdateAppointment(),

```
{
    "docID": "id assigned by mongoDB",
    "appointment": {
        "patientID": "id assigned by mongoDB",
        "dataAndTime": "IIII"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct just change `foundData` with `DoctorModel` when you want to update the data. So the code becomes:

```
            else {
DoctorModel.update({'_id':docID, 'appointmentList.patientID' : jsonObject.appointment.patientID}, {$set: {'appointmentList.$': jsonObject.appointment}},
                    function(err, updatedData) {....});
```